# How far in the future can I create events on my calendar?

Tags: calendar

My calendar does not accept events for September 2016 or beyond but will for May 2016.   Is there a limited time frame or horizon ?

Comment: Which calendar? What OS?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to the API limitations itself and vary on different platforms, device, regional settings etc. However you can get some functions blocked if you create to many events or calendars in short period of time.

**Google**: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en

**iCal**: support.apple.com/en-us/HT202158

How to Hit the limits of Google calendar:

> If a user sees one of these messages it’s probably due to one of the
>   following reasons:
>
> ```
> Creating too many events
>
> If a user has created more than 10,000 events in his or her calendar within a short period of time, that user might lose calendar edit access.
>
> Creating too many calendars
>
> If a user creates more than 25 new calendars within a short period of time, that user's calendar might go into read-only mode.
>
> Sending too many invitations or emails to external guests
>
> In order to prevent spamming, Google Calendar limits the number of invitations a user can send to external guests. This limit varies
> ```
>
> depending on the action, and is usually between 100-300 guests.
>
> ```
> Google Apps users can send invitations to any number of guests from their primary domain, or from secondary domains associated with
> ```
>
> their primary domain.
>
> ```
> Sharing calendars with too many users
>
> If a user shares one or more calendars with many other users within a short period of time, Google Calendar might switch into
> ```
>
> read-only mode for that user. It’s almost impossible to reach this
>   limit by updating sharing settings manually, but it can happen with
>   some API-based tools or third-party apps.

Comment: what API limitation ? could you link to the source of your information !

Comment: @Buscar Congrats on 20k but please familiarise yourself fully with the criteria for when you should vote to delete before using your new privilege, to prevent any inappropriate actions from taking place.

Comment: @grgarside where are the criteria ?